# Table modification text alignment

Tags: tables

I have constructed a table that needs some modification.
[image]

There are two problems:

1. In the first row second column, the text expands the table border
2. In the second row first column, the text expands the table border

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{EFEFEF}

\begin{longtable}[H]{|
>{\columncolor{lightgray}}p{0.2\linewidth} | p{0.175\linewidth} | p{0.125\linewidth} | p{0.15\linewidth} | p{0.225\linewidth} |}
\hline \hline
\textbf{BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA }                                               & \multicolumn{4}{p{0.7\linewidth}|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA  \\ \\ BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA  \\ BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA  \\ BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA  \end{tabular}}
\\ \hline \hline
BLA\_BLA\_BLA\_BLA\_BLA\_BLA\_BLA\_BLA & \multicolumn{4}{p{0.7\linewidth}|}{}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I don't understand what went wrong. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your innermost `tabular` uses an `l` column, it needs a `p{\linewidth}` column instead.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{EFEFEF}

\begin{longtable}[H]{|
>{\columncolor{lightgray}}p{0.2\linewidth} | p{0.175\linewidth} | p{0.125\linewidth} | 
  p{0.15\linewidth} | p{0.225\linewidth} |}
\hline \hline
\textbf{BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA }
 & \multicolumn{4}{p{0.7\linewidth}|}
  {\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}} BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA
 BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA  \\ \\ 
 BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA  \\
 BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA 
 BLA BLA BLA  \\ 
 BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA  
  \end{tabular}}
\\ \hline \hline
BLA\_BLA\_BLA\_BLA\_BLA\_BLA\_BLA\_BLA & \multicolumn{4}{p{0.7\linewidth}|}{}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your `table` within a `table`. You chose an `l` option that does not cause a line break. Replace with `p{\linewidth}` and the lines break just fine.

It needs to be `\linewidth` to adjust to the fact that the `\linewidth` is already defined by the overarching `table`.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

```
\begin{document}
    
    \definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{EFEFEF}
    
    \begin{longtable}[ht]{>{\columncolor{lightgray}}p{0.2\linewidth} | p{0.175\linewidth} | p{0.125\linewidth} | p{0.15\linewidth} | p{0.225\linewidth} |}
        \hline \hline
        \textbf{BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA } & \multicolumn{4}{p{0.7\linewidth}|}{
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}} BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA  \\ 
                \\ 
                BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA  \\ BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA  \\ 
                BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA  \end{tabular}
            }
        \\ \hline \hline
        BLA\_BLA\_BLA\_BLA\_BLA\_BLA\_BLA\_BLA & \multicolumn{4}{p{0.7\linewidth}|}{}
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The problem with the second issue is, that LaTeX does not know where to break this line, so either remove the `\_` or add a `\-` somewhere.